# get word after a tag closing using regex?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, function

I have following string

```
<strong>Test: </strong> BD-F5300
```

I am interested in getting number `BD-F5300`. Number could be of any thing text,number.

Any help, how can I get it? Thanks.

Comment: We need a lot more specifics here.  Is this text surrounded by anything?  Are there more rules for the string we are searching for?

Comment: @ExplosionPills no i have just this only string. only thing that will be change is that number or may be that word between strong.

Comment: @MarcB but i am looking the regex for my answer?

Comment: Regexes + HTML = madness:http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068  **DON'T TRY IT**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to get some content after `</strong>` then you can just use:

```
preg_match('@</strong> (.+)@', $string, $matches);
```

The desired match will be in `$matches[1]`.  However, this requires that the `<strong>` tag and the text content you want to find are both on the same line.  If there are multiples of these you want to match, you may want to use `preg_match_all`

Comment: thanks but i guess it should be @<\/strong> (.+)@. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

### You could make use of [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)

```
<?php
$str='<strong>Test: </strong> BD-F5300';
echo $str = preg_replace("~<(/)?strong>(.*?)<(/)?strong>~","", $str);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
BD-F5300
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

do like this in JavaScript:

```
var src = "<strong>Test: </strong> BD-F5300";
var reg = /.*<\/.*>\s*([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/g;
var group = reg.exec(src);
console.log(group[1]+'\r\n'); //group[1] is what you want !
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is always a space before the beginning of the final text you want and if there are never any spaces in the actual number text you want, you can avoid regex by doing this:

```
$str = '<strong>Test: </strong> BD-F5300';
$solution = substr($str, strrpos($str, ' ') + 1);
var_dump($solution);
```